# My Unity Script Wont work?

Tags: c#, random, unity-game-engine

Hi I have a script attached to the main camera, and in this script I want to choose a number between 0 to 5 . And depending on what number I get, I want a script to run. Hers my script that is attached to the main camera. I keep getting this error

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object RandomFunction.Start () (at Assets/Resources/Scripts/RandomFunction.cs:22)

```
using UnityEngine;
   using System.Collections;
   public class RandomFunction : MonoBehaviour {
     int n;
     void Awake()
     {
         GetComponent<RandomFunction> ().enabled = true;
     }
     void Start () 
     {
         n=Random.Range(0,5);
         if(n==0)
         {
             GetComponent<BlueGoUp> ().enabled = true;
         }
         else if(n==1)
         {
             GetComponent<RedGoUp> ().enabled = true;
         }
         else if(n==2)
         {
             GetComponent<GreenGoUp> ().enabled = true;
         }
         else if(n==3)
         {
             GetComponent<OrangeGoUp> ().enabled = true;
         }
         else if(n==4)
         {
             GetComponent<YellowGoUp> ().enabled = true;
         }
         else if(n==5)
          {
             GetComponent<PurpleGoUp> ().enabled = true;
         }
     }

 }
```

Comment: You should consider using a `switch` statement instead of `if`-`else`. Also, are these scripts enabled to `true` by default? Because I'm pretty sure you don't have to turn on the script running on the object.

Comment: there all disabled on Start()

Comment: So when you disable them on `Start()` nothing happens? No `null` exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove `Awake()` method because it is really unnecessary to active `RandomFunction` script from here. Active that in inspector.
2. I'm not sure if use component like this was correct. I always use `gameObject.GetComponent`
3. `if(n==5)` will never be true because `Random.Range(0,5)` return `0,1,2,3 or 4` .
   from the document:

   > Range(**int** min, **int** max), Returns a random integer number between min [inclusive] and max [exclusive] (Read Only).
4. Use `switch case` statement instead of `If else`

Your final code should look like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class RandomFunction : MonoBehaviour {
int n;

void Start () 
{
    n=Random.Range(0,6);

    switch (n)
    {
        case 0:
            gameobject.GetComponent<BlueGoUp> ().enabled = true;
            break;
        case 1:
            gameObject.GetComponent<RedGoUp> ().enabled = true;
            break;
        case 2:
            gameObject.GetComponent<GreenGoUp> ().enabled = true;
            break;
        case 3:
            gameObject.GetComponent<OrangeGoUp> ().enabled = true;
            break;
        case 4:
            gameObject.GetComponent<YellowGoUp> ().enabled = true;
            break;
        case 5:
            gameObject.GetComponent<PurpleGoUp> ().enabled = true;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, you don't need to do what you're doing in the Awake function because:

1. The MonoBehaviour object being used *is* the one attached to the GameObject. If you don't get what I mean, supposed you attached `RandomFunction` to a CameraObj. Now, that instance of `RandomFunction` (`this` pointer in script) is equal to or is same as `CameraObj.GetComponent<RandomFunction>()`, since you can't add more than one of the same component to a GameObject.
2. The `Awake()` method won't be executed *till the object is **actually** enabled.* Thus you won't need to re-enable the object in the script, because if it is executing, the object is enabled already.

Remove the `Awake` method and it should also remove the `NullReferenceException`. If it still doesn't, make sure that *the same object* (which has the `RandomFunction` component) also has the components `BlueGoUp`, `RedGoUp`, `YellowGoUp`, `GreenGoUp`, `OrangeGoUp` and `PurpleGoUp`.

Oh, and your `if (n==5)` condition will never be true, since 5 will never be returned by `Random.Range()`. The `max` parameter is always exclusive for integers in the `Random.Range()` function, thus the value returned will always be `min <= value < max`.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably and I am hoping that all the GoUp scripts are not attached to the Camera. So find script in another way. Try to replace your code by this,

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class RandomFunction : MonoBehaviour {
    int n;
    void Awake()
    {
        GetComponent<RandomFunction> ().enabled = true;
    }
    void Start () 
    {
        n=Random.Range(0,6);
        switch(n){
        case 0:
            FindObjectOfType<BlueGoUp>().enabled = true;
            break;
        case 1:
            FindObjectOfType<RedGoUp>().enabled = true;
            break;
        case 2:
            FindObjectOfType<GreenGoUp>().enabled = true;
            break;
        case 3:
            FindObjectOfType<OrangeGoUp>().enabled = true;
            break;
        case 4:
            FindObjectOfType<YellowGoUp>().enabled = true;
            break;
        case 5:
            FindObjectOfType<PurpleGoUp>().enabled = true;
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

If this code will not work then there is no way other than that your scripts are not dropped on any gameObjects.